# How can I increase the wireless signal in my home

Tags: wireless-networking

I have Dlink router with ADSL connection. But my wireless singnal is very weak and I cannot move the router as it is fixed near the telephone line.

I have tried some recommendations, but still it is weak and I have to be closer to router most of the time to get full signal.

Answer (score 3):

You have several options to extend the wireless signal in your house.

- Check the wireless spectrum with any of the network scanning utilities available, it's possible that your wireless range is degraded due to neighbouring wifi signals in the same channel, try to move to another channel if that's the case
- You can buy a wireless range extender, they'll just repeat the original wireless signal, for best results in bonding them I'm always favourable to buy wireless extenders from the same provider as your DSL router, in this case D-Link. You can use other wireless extenders but your experience may vary
- Last option and this for me a very good one, try setting up another wireless access point in your house, if you can't put physical ethernet cable, buy one of the ethernet over power plugs solutions, that's the one I'm using in my house and it's extremely reliable

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the DLINK router it may be possible to install a alternative firmware such as DD-WRT which, I think, allows you to boost the signal a little.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound like a stupid question but did you try going in to Advanced Wireless => Advanced and set the Transmit Power to High?

[image]

Comment: None of the other answers mentions this basic option. It looks like many of us assume other users would do such an "obvious" thing. When you think about it, it may not be so obvious for the average Joe. Lesson taken. Yes, this answer should definitely be here. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try [making a reflector](http://www.binarywolf.com/249/diy-parabolic-reflector.htm) on the router first, then if it didn't solve the problem, try adding one on the PC Wifi antenna then if that didn't work add a repeater.

Comment: A wok or large metal salad bowl works in a pinch to test this theory.  Hold the reflector so that the antenna is at the focal point (where light focuses if shined into the reflector.)  If you get a good connection, I suggest you replace your stock antenna(s) with directional ones.

Answer (score 0):

If your router is compatible with software such as DD-WRT you can flash your router with better software than it comes with to start with, but that it also allows you to boost the physical power of the amplifier from inside the router.

Make sure to do some reading on the correct levels to set this as since it's very similar to increasing the voltage to PC components for overclocking it will cause additional heat build up. If you wish to boost it substantially you will want to open up your router and install a custom heatsink that's better suited for the additional load.